# How to re-add existing (missing) BTRFs device without removing it first

Tags: btrfs

I added a new HDD to my BTRFS pool (4th device), all was fine for 20 minutes, then Arch Linux reported it as a read-only file system.
I mistakenly rebooted and the system refused to boot (stopped at maintenance menu), so I commented out the BTRFs FSTAB entry and rebooted ok.
Now we see

```
sudo btrfs filesystem show Label: none  uuid: 8dac8c7b-e793-4b32-8085-05acb581c7ea
        Total devices 4 FS bytes used 21.28TiB
        devid    1 size 7.28TiB used 7.12TiB path /dev/sdd
        devid    2 size 7.28TiB used 7.11TiB path /dev/sdc
        devid    3 size 7.28TiB used 7.11TiB path /dev/sdb
        *** Some devices missing
```

Device 4 has meta data on, so I don't want to REMOVE it and re-add.  Is there a way to re-add without removing first?
Note, that this is the same drive, if I try to add it into the pool, it asks for a -f to force an overwrite of the drive.
Is it possible to do without an overwrite, so it reads the drive and realises it is part of the pool.

Comment: What does `sudo btrfs device scan` show?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
ERROR: dev_item UUID does not match fsid: 162e1cf7-d4f7-4421-80e4-1b88123ace02 != 252fb1c8-7840-4ffa-8a76-58f7019a5e4a
ERROR: superblock checksum matches but it has invalid members
ERROR: cannot scan /dev/sdd3: Input/output error

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, and what worked was to unmount and re-mount using the dev path of the missing-but-not-really disk:

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /media/source # (no good)
umount /media/source
mount /dev/sdc2 /media/source # (good)
```

Hope it helps. BTW `btrfs device scan` has always shown nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem show /mnt/btrfs/
Label: none  uuid: 162e1cf7-d4f7-4421-80e4-1b88123ace02
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 588.05GiB
    devid    1 size 1.24TiB used 590.01GiB path /dev/sdc3
    *** Some devices missing

$ sudo btrfs replace start -B 2 /dev/sdd3 /mnt/btrfs
```